# Do we do anything to "network error" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Everyday hundreds of questions caused by network issues emerge. Examples include:

- (Git or SSH) `cannot connect to github.com port 443: connection timed out`
- All kinds of package managers:

  - pip `ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.`
  - NPM `ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://`
  - VS Code extension install
- Or whatever error message caused by a poor connectivity to the Internet

I do find it boring to tell the OPs "check your network connectivity" over and over again, so I just vote to close as "not reproducible" (an answer would be boring and not helpful to anyone else). My question is, shall we (or can we?) do anything to this phenomenon? I'm also finding it difficult to put together an FAQ in a form suitable for SO.

Comment: I am sympathetic to this, particular tags will fall victim to people who get an error and then immediately want someone else to make it go away because their tutorial makes the assumption that everything will always go perfect. To me this seems like a similar situation to the NullPointerException; thousands of reasons why you could get it, most simply ask for debugging, no answer on Stack Overflow will have a magic wand to make it go away. So thinking along those lines the least bad solution would be a similarly generic canonical for connectivity errors.

Comment: they are part of programming so yeahh tey belong here

Comment: @nbk Of course; these questions aren’t strictly off-topic, just either duplicates or no-repro (note that the “not reproducible” reason starts with _“While similar questions may be on-topic here, \[…\]”_ despite being a subreason of “off-topic”). This question isn’t to discuss whether “network error” questions are out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Such questions belong here, but can be referred to another site, if they want. a sql connection question, can have many causes so we can try to see where it hurts, that is strictly not orogramming, but as long as they are not DBA related, we answer them, it can be a ors related problem and we answer them, stiil some questionbeolong to network/Server/dba and we advise to ask there when teh answer is not quickly resolved, so try your best answer them if you can or refer them to a better side here in the network

Comment: Some of them are not that bad. If I remember correctly there was not so long ago a a question about "Response timeout while trying to fetch https://" that was a bug in the last version of that package. And was hightly upvoted as every user that update was looking for an answers.

Comment: @DragandDrop and afterwards was long forgotten because nobody will use a version with such crippling bug.

Comment: It should be needless to say that there are always exceptions to the rule. This isn't about those exceptions though.

Comment: Idea: A community maintained list of (Regex, Q&A) tuples, with which answers get scanned upon submit, and all that match  get shown to the asker before the question gets submitted.

Comment: Would a "What are common causes for [insert network issue]?" question be ontopic? If so, we could close all these questions as non reproducible and still refer to this question. It may not solve the problem, but it is all the help we could give, maybe even automatically. What bugs me most is that people don't google their problem. I feel like a broken record when typing "Have you searched for it? What have you found?".

Comment: @Trilarion careful about that, you will be threading the path of the NPE question.

Comment: I have the impress that some questions about connectivity problems can lead to the creation of reusable knowledge (e.g. about the configuration of the tool / library that was throwing the connectivity problem). I'm thinking for example about questions and answer about Docker and DNS settings (such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761246/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-errno-3-with-docker or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832972/docker-apt-get-update-fails).

Comment: @mgc Both of those are dupes of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/docker-network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network so good job torpedoing your own argument...

Comment: @IanKemp Glad it helped to find duplicates not marked as such until then ;)

Answer (score 42):

They should be closed as Duplicates of the canonical highly viewed, highly upvoted questions that exist for each of the errors:

- [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)
- [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)
- [npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is (over 30000ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378672/npm-err-response-timeout-while-trying-to-fetch-https-registry-npmjs-org-react)

If such a question doesn't exist on Stack Overflow, the new question should be Answered and left open and will eventually become the dupe-target.

I don't see why "network errors" with a clear, searchable error message should be treated differently than any other errors programmers might hit while using those tools.

Comment: I don't see why the part of this answer up until "If such a question doesn't exist on Stack Overflow" is needed: that part of this answer is specific to the examples presented, not the actual question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unless it's a particularly obscure tool or problem, a duplicate probably already exists. Those examples serve to demonstrate that fact.

Comment: So basically: bookmark those suckers to have quick access to them.

Comment: @Gimby when I see a question that's surely a dupe, I google for the error message and usually find the right SO question as the first result. If only the Asker would do that...

Comment: Those questions are unclear: the git one didn't say that their corporate network uses proxy, which if they did it would have been closed against [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496277/792066), but apparently they didn't even know which proxy were they using, the second one is basically the servers being slow or the network being flaky, there's nothing magical about a 100 seconds timeout, same with the npm error. They are all localized issues to the network of the one asking the question that didn't know what their problem even was.

Comment: @Braiam but are the answers unclear? They look fine to me. Besides: "They are all localized issues to the network of the one asking the question that didn't know what their problem even was" - yeah, that is kind of what this meta post is about. Managing exactly such situations.

Comment: @Gimby the questions are unclear, that's the point of close reasons. Closing questions. Who cares if the answerer makes any sense out of a crystal ball and just managed to soul read the cosmic waves.

Comment: `I don't see why "network errors" with a clear, searchable error message should be treated differently than any other errors programmers might hit while using those tools.` By the same argument we should have canonicals for **every single underlying OS error that these tools could ever surface**.

Comment: @IanKemp I agree, yes.

Comment: @IanKemp No, just the common ones.

Answer (score 19):

No, I think your current process for handling these questions is about as far as we should go.

These questions have intrinsically no value and show zero research or attempt to understand the problem on behalf of the asker. Since the askers have not even done the bare minimum of a Google search, why should we do anything more than vote to close?

That extends to creating a FAQ, which I'm strongly against, because it's either going to be a one-liner that the askers could've got from Google if they weren't lazy sods, or it's going to grow into an amorphous monster encapsulating every possible reason that someone could have network connectivity issues a la the NullReferenceException canonical - in other words, not helpful either way.

Unless the bar to entry to Stack Overflow is raised, we are going to keep getting these hordes of junk questions. Unless curation tools are improved, there is really nothing we can do except VTC such questions on sight.

VTC, downvote (so that the question becomes eligible for deletion), move on.

Comment: So essentially your answer is "no, nothing can be done to help ease the pain". I defend to the death your right to post this answer within 3 hours of the discussion question being posted, but at the same time it seems a little soon to throw in the towel.

Comment: @Gimby VTC'ing the question is the proper action. Its not throwing in the towel, its just recommending to exercise ones curating abilities.

Comment: @Gimby If you have other options to suggest, **post them as an answer**. I've covered the only options I can see, but I am only one fallible person.

Comment: @Gimby there is an implicit solution in this post: raise the barrier to asking questions. It's an unpopular one for a variety of reasons, but there are also a significant number of factors suggesting it might be the right approach.

Comment: @user3386109 Corrected.

Comment: @user1937198 Morally I agree, but there has to be a moment where you let go of false hope.

Comment: The problem I see with this action, is that it will take 3 votes to close it, rather than a single duplicate vote, as suggested in pkamb's answer. Basically duping it will be 3 times as fast, and if the questions are truly unresearched, basal and shitty, they won't get enough attention to escape the duplicate roomba, hopefully.

Comment: @Adriaan why don't you ask for gold badges owners to also be able to single vote unclear or off topic questions? Duplicates are not the appropriate close reason when other close reasons apply.

Comment: "Unless the bar to entry to Stack Overflow is raised" - Oh, did James Cameron register?